# How to scale a rotated child element to fit its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this element with the following dimensions `width: 90px`  `height: 108px`

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC7Of.png)

After rotating it's size "gets bigger"

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfkUr.png)

How can I scale it so it fits its container with any rotating angle?

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NhF.png)

**Code:**

```css
figure {
  grid-area: image;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  width: min(50vw, 90px);
  height: min(60vw, 108px);
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 1.2rem;
    border: 6px solid var(--white);
  }
}
```

Ps: I'm using JSS, so any JavaScript solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you saying the container dimensions are fixed at 90px 108px? Does the image always have that aspect ratio?

Comment: Hi. Yes the container dimensions shpuld be fixed. The image aspect ratio should always be the same.